# Nested list (tree) - how to nest elements by dragging to the right?

Tags: sortablejs, vuedraggable, vue.draggable

What would be the approach with Vue.Draggable/SortableJS in order to achieve the functionality as shown in [this animated gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7U5D.gif)?

The default behavior of Sortable for nesting is to drag the element up to the above element until the mouse reaches `emptyInsertThreshold` pixels from the drop zone of the above element but I would like to be able to nest elements by dragging them to the right. Same for un-nesting.

I have set `emptyInsertThreshold` to `0` to disable the default behavior and now when I drag the element to the right I get the following events fired: `clone` and `start` (in that order).

But how do I:

1. Can get notified when the mouse has traveled the pre-defined distance to the right?
2. Inform Vue.Draggable that the ghost element should be nested as a child to the element under which I am doing the horizontal movement?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mouse position given in the start event under `event.originalEvent` and in the onMove event using the `originalEvent` argument (2nd argument). I would track the % that the mouse is past the end of the list item above the dragged item, using: `(clientX - aboveItemStart) / aboveItemWidth`. Then when it reaches 10% or so, change the DOM directly using `event.dragged`. Not sure how you would modify it to work with Vue.Draggable... you might need to edit the Vue.Draggable source.

Comment: Unfortunately `onMove` is not fired when an element is dragged horizontally. `onMove` is fired only when the element is dragged onto the drop zone of another draggable element, which is the default behavior and not what I want. When dragging horizontally, only `onClone` and `onStart` are fired (`onChoose` also but it is irrelevant in this case). What can I do with those?